# Why aren't antenna signals inside smartphones stopped by the metal case?

Tags: antenna, metal, smartphones

Our smartphones or other device are surrounded by metal, yet there are plenty of antennas inside it (NFC, 4G, Bluetooth, ...).

How can it work ? Isn't the metal supposed to block RF signals ?

Comment: Yet an antenna is made from metal.... Please consider reviewing the questions you have asked and formally accepting answers that gave you the information that you needed.

Comment: Have you... googled? http://www.antenna-theory.com/design/cellantenna.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smartphone cases aren't metal.

Cheap ones are made of plastic (ABS or polycarbonate). The very high end ones which have glass front and back and metal edging will often use the metal edging itself as the antenna. [This caused problems on the iPhone 4 when used by left-handers.](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2010/06/new-iphone-4-antenna-causing-potential-reception-issues/) In that design, the metal bezel was split into carefully sized pieces that were not connected, so that some could serve as antennas of the correct length.

It can be surprisingly difficult to stop a phone working by putting it in a metal box, because the waves are quite short and good at diffracting out of small gaps. What normally happens is it turns up the radio power to its maximum in order to communicate with the base station.

Answer (score 0):

Only certain configurations of metal block RF.  A enclosing Faraday cage for instance.

Other configurations of metal (or other conductors or magnetics) radiate EM when driven. A wire dipole antenna for instance, or the reflectors and directors in a Yagi Uda.

They radiate EM when electrical charges (electrons, et.al.) accelerate along the wire.

Slots or separations in a solid metal plane can also be used to radiate (or re-radiate) EM.  Most cell phones have these openings, usually of very carefully selected dimensions.

Slots or cuts radiate EM when charges are made to accelerate around the insulated opening.  Lots of other possible geometries.

Answer (score 0):

Metal is efficient in blocking electromagnetic waves when surrounding an entire volume forming what is called a Faraday cage. So if you place your cell phone in a cage like that I can assure you that it's not going to be able to communicate with the outside world. You can use an empty paint gallon as a cheap DIY Faraday cage, if you want to test it by yourself.

The simple presence of metal structures nearby the cell phone antennas won't block the electromagnetic waves. That's not to say it doesn't affect the generation and propagation of the waves at all. Actually, when designing the antennas the engineer has to take the presence of these metallic parts into account in order to properly tune the antennas. In some cases it's fair to say that certain metal structures are actually part of the radiating structure of the antenna.